# Browser Close Immediately | Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I start to learn selenium today. I install chrome driver and firefox driver accoding to version. I try with both chrome and firefox but browsers closes immediately. I also add drivers to PATH. I also try using direct path of driver

Chrome Version: 109.0.5414.120

Selenium Version: 4.8

Python Version: 3.8

Conda Version: 23.1.0

Code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
service = Service(r"C:\Users\Sarper\Drivers\chromedriver.exe")
print(selenium.__version__)  # Verison 4.8
chrome_browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
chrome_browser.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it closes, because your code is done running.

You might try:

```py
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
service = Service(r"C:\Users\Sarper\Drivers\chromedriver.exe")
print(selenium.__version__)  # Verison 4.8
chrome_browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
chrome_browser.get("https://www.google.com")

input("Press ENTER to exit\n")
```

Comment: Is it normal to close before I close ?

Comment: Yes, when your code is done running, it automatically closes. PLease mark the answer which you think is the answer to yor question as THE ANSWER.

Answer (score 2):

`Service` need to get the path to the `chromedriver.exe` as following:

```py
service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
```

`C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe` here is the actual path to `chromedriver.exe` on my computer

To keep the browser open set `options` with `detach` = `true`, as wollowing:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service)
```

Comment: Yes, I also try that but it didn't worked.

Comment: What error did you see?

Comment: No error, only it is directly close after opening.

Comment: What if you put a delay like `time.sleep(5)` after `chrome_browser.get("https://www.google.com")`? Will it keep it open for 5 seconds?

Comment: Yet it's waiting for 5 seconds

Comment: I also tried reinstalling chrome

Comment: So thanks but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Selenium Version
print(webdriver.__version__)

# Instantiating the Chrome driver
chrome_browser = webdriver.Chrome()

# Opening the browser to Google website
chrome_browser.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Comment: webdriver version is 4.8.0 and it didn't work it's still closing directly

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post